# Class.forName(clazz.getName()); throw java.lang.ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, jar, classloader

I am loading in jar files dynamically and while loading in the jar I save all the `Class` objects to a `List`. After loading in all the jars I execute the code below and it throws a `java.lang.ClassNotFoundException` pointing to `Class.forName(clazz.getName())`. I am not sure why java cannot find the class even though it is clearly loaded, can someone please explain.

```
    Class<?> clazz = listOfClasses.get(0);
    try {
        Class.forName(clazz.getName());
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Comment: How are you loading the Jar? 
Definitely classes are in different class loaders. You could do something like this before invoking "forName":
`Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(clazz.getClassloader())`

Optionally, you can create a Composite Classloader to be set, like the one here:
http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Language-Basics/ClassLoaderthatiscomposedofotherclassloaders.htm

Answer (score 0):

`Class.forName(String)` uses the classloader of the code that's calling `Class.forName`.  It sounds like you might be dynamically loading the classes in a different class loader?

Comment: One could test this by getting the `ClassLoader` for `clazz`, then invoking `loadClass(String)` like so: `clazz.getClassLoader().loadClass(clazz.getName())`. If that works, this answer is likely correct.

Comment: thanks, I still don't have the reputation for a +1 but that wwas it, thanks

Answer (score 0):

As you say you are loading classes dynamically and clearly they are in a different classloader than the code that does the `Class.forName`. In that case, you need to pass the classloader to `Class.forName` as well:

```
Class<?> clazz = listOfClasses.get(0);
try {
    Class.forName(clazz.getName(), true, clazz.getClassLoader());
} catch(Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: thanks, I still don't have the reputation for a +1 but that wwas it, thanks

Comment: @Ozaren You can accept an answer to your question to indicate the answer that resolves your question best: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work